# Knife command failing to authenticate

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have created a setup as below, and for all this I am using Amazon EC2:

An ubuntu server 12.04 ion which I have a Chef server installed and knife configured. This is working perfectly fine, I am able to run the knife commands and it is giving me expected results.

Another similar ubuntu server I am trying to use it as a chef client. Installed chef and configured the client. Also, installed knife on the client. I know this is installed properly because after installation I ran the command

```
knife --version
```

I got the output

```
Chef: 10.16.2
```

Now I have configured the knife.rb file. 
The contents are as follows:
    log_level            :info
    log_location         STDOUT
    node_name           'knife'
    cache_type          'BasicFile'
    cache_options( :path => "~/.chef/checksums" )
    client_key       '~/.chef/clientkey.pem'

```
cookbook_path       [ "~/mychefrepo/cookbooks" ]
cookbook_copyright "example org"
cookbook_email     "cookbooks@example.net"
cookbook_license   "apachev2"

chef_server_url    "http://ip-11-213-23-99:4000"

validation_key      "~/.chef/validation.pem"
```

After the configuration If I run the knife command

```
knife client list
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Failed to authenticate to http://ip-11-213-23-99:4000 as client1 with key /etc/chef/clientkeys.pem

I would request you to please clear my following doubts:

1. Is it mandatory to keep the clientkey.pem on the chef server too? If yes then at what location?
2. Is there any specific location where I need to keep the pem file on chef client?
3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your solution referenced below ?  I am experiencing this issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your client exists on the chef-server appropriately? I believe it will be called 'knife' as this is your node_name.

```
http://ip-11-213-23-99:4040/clients
```

The client pem key does get registered with the server as you can see via the server-webui by going to the clients tab on the server. The key is stored in CouchDB. This value gets here when you perform a chef-client run with the server.

The value of the supplied pem key has to match the stored pem shown in the client view for the 'node_name' you supplied. Is that the case?

The client key itself can be stored anywhere.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to check if the client exists on the chef-server appropriately or not. I would check if you tell me how to.
Moreover, I created the client on the chef server with the help of knife CLI in on the chef server, so I believe it would be proper. 
Anyhow, I would verify the key in the couch db.

Comment: If you vist the link above replacing with your actual ip you should see a list of all configured api clients. You should look for one with the same name as the 'node_name' in your knife.rb and check the value of it's key by clicking on it. Compare this with the pem key you are submitting with knife.rb. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks .. I was able to solve the issue by some other way.. :)

But your answer game me a point to think.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Mind sharing what was the other way you solved it ? That would help other readers.

Comment: I'm running into this problem.  Please share your answer with the community.  It's not good to leech answers, but not contribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you bootstrap the client from server it creates client.pem there. or even when you run chef-client on client itself it creates client.pem.
This file you need to copy on server node.
Again you have to provide the path into knife.rb which available in /chef-repo/.chef

1. Yes it is neccassary to copy it.
2. Anywhere on server node but oly thing is that you have to provide that location in knife.rb